# Passing javascript variable to another function using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass the id which is

```
var aid = post.id;
```

to the message container and when the a onClick is being clicked, the page should alert the aid value. Other records are being displayed properly. However, the problem here is that it is saying aid is undefined. How do i fix this issue?

```
var message_container = '<div class=\"new-update clearfix\"><div class=\"update-done\"></br> </div> <a onClick="reject('+ aid + ');" id="aid" class=\"tip\" ><i style=\"font-size: 2em; float:right\"  class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a> </br></br> </div>';
        $.ajax({
        url : '/test/back-api/admin/announcements',
        method : 'GET',
        success : function(d) {
            if (d.result) {
                var posts = d.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                    var post = posts[i];
                    var aid = post.id;
                    //message.find('#aid').append("href", post.id);
                    $("#announcement-container").prepend(message);
                }
            } else {
                $('#announcement-container').append("<div> Nothing to show. </div>");
            }
        }
});
var reject = function(aid){
     $.ajax({
     url: app.api + "admin/transaction/remove/"+aid,
     type: 'post',
     success: function(d){
       alert(aid);
     }
})
```

Comment: Define `aid` outside `ajax` call and assign value in success. It's all about `scope` of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var message_container = $('<div class=\"new-update clearfix\"><div class=\"update-done\"></br> </div> <a onClick="reject('+ aid + ');" id="aid" class=\"tip\" ><i style=\"font-size: 2em; float:right\"  class=\"icon-remove\"></i></a> </br></br> </div>');
$.ajax({
    url : '/test/back-api/admin/announcements',
    method : 'GET',
    success : function(d) {
        if (d.result) {
            var posts = d.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                var post = posts[i];
                $(message_container).find('#aid').attr("onClick", "reject('"+ post.id + "')");
                $("#announcement-container").prepend($(message_container).clone(true));
            }
        } else {
            $('#announcement-container').append("<div> Nothing to show. </div>");
        }
    }
});
var reject = function(aid){
     $.ajax({
         url: app.api + "admin/transaction/remove/"+aid,
         type: 'post',
         success: function(d){
           alert(aid);
         }
    });
}
```

Please see the updated answer.

Comment: error unexpected EOI. To add code, use the code block. Use snippet only for working code

Comment: @ErrorinException: I've changed my code to snippet. I'll keep this in mind. I've updated my answer.

Comment: better to replace $("#announcement-container").prepend($(message_container)); as $("#announcement-container").prepend($(message_container).clone(true)); to make it different for each prepend. I've again updated my answer.

Comment: @JohnWick & gjijo: Problems with the above: 1. Using the same ID on multiple elements is invalid HTML. 2. There's zero reason to use the `onClick` attribute when you're hooking up the event handler (either handle the [closures-in-loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) aspect, or set it as a data attribute on the element, etc).

Comment: Also <a> tag will force redirect in certain browsers, even if the click event is explicitly specified. So its better to change it as some button with on click event, or reload the same page using <a< itself, so as to display the updated answer.

Comment: @gjijo: No, an `a` with no `href` will not react to a click other than to fire its click event.

Comment: Oh sorry, @JohnWick has commented the changing of href value. I didnt noticed the same and included it in my answer. Removed it and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `aid` in an `onxyx`-attribute-style event handler, it has to be a global. That's one of many reasons not to use them.

Instead, hook up the event handler with modern handling, store the `aid` on the link as a `data-*` attribute, and retrieve it in `reject`:

```
// *** Removed `onClick` and `id="aid"` from this string
var message_container = '<div class=\"new-update clearfix\"><div class=\"update-done\"></br> </div> <a class=\"tip\" ><i style=\"font-size: 2em; float:right\"  class=\"icon-remove\">remove link</i></a> </br></br> </div>';
$.ajax({
    url : '/test/back-api/admin/announcements',
    method : 'GET',
    success : function(d) {
        if (d.result) {
            var posts = d.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                var post = posts[i];
                var aid = post.id;
                //message.find('#aid').append("href", post.id);
                // *** Hook it up and prepend it
                $(message_container)               
                    .find("a.tip")
                        .attr("data-aid", aid)
                        .on("click", reject)
                        .end()
                    .prependTo("#announcement-container");
                // *** End of added bit
            }
        } else {
            $('#announcement-container').append("<div> Nothing to show. </div>");
        }
    }
});
function reject() {
    var aid = this.getAttribute("data-aid"); // *** Get the aid from the element
    alert("reject aid = " + aid);
}
```

Note that I removed the `id="aid"` from the string. You can't have the same ID on more than one element.

Live example:

```js
// *** Removed `onClick` and `id="aid"` from this string
var message_container = '<div class=\"new-update clearfix\"><div class=\"update-done\"></br> </div> <a class=\"tip\" ><i style=\"font-size: 2em; float:right\"  class=\"icon-remove\">remove link</i></a> </br></br> </div>';
fakeAjax({
    url : '/test/back-api/admin/announcements',
    method : 'GET',
    success : function(d) {
        if (d.result) {
            var posts = d.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                var post = posts[i];
                var aid = post.id;
                //message.find('#aid').append("href", post.id);
                // *** Hook it up and prepend it
                $(message_container)               
                    .find("a.tip")
                        .attr("data-aid", aid)
                        .on("click", reject)
                        .end()
                    .prependTo("#announcement-container");
                // *** End of added bit
            }
        } else {
            $('#announcement-container').append("<div> Nothing to show. </div>");
        }
    }
});
function reject() {
    var aid = this.getAttribute("data-aid"); // *** Get the aid from the element
    alert("reject aid = " + aid);
}
function fakeAjax(options) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        options.success({
            result: true,
            data: [
                {id: 1},
                {id: 2},
                {id: 3}
            ]
        });
    }, 300);
}
```

```html
<div id="announcement-container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to change `reject`, then just change the handler from:

```
.on("click", reject)
```

to

```
.on("click", reject.bind(null, aid))
```

and leave the rest the same.

Comment: I have tried this, it actually appends another 2 extra rows and didn't alert anything

Comment: @JohnWick: I had planned to just leave it, since the solution you marked accepted does work even if it's quite poor. But I felt like I'd done a bad job, so I finished doing it. See above, including live example.